# Using ArcPy to add a field to an existing file geodatabase feature class

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, fields-attributes

I was using this example to try and add a field to a feature class I created in a fileGDB:

```
arcpy.management.AddField(in_table, field_name, field_type, {field_precision}, {field_scale}, {field_length}, {field_alias}, {field_is_nullable}, {field_is_required}, {field_domain})
```

I created this:

```
arcpy.management.AddField(r"C:\Users\acarbo\Documents\ArcGIS\Projects\PythonTest.GDB\Admin2", "Country_Name", "TEXT", field_length=10, field_alias="Name")
```

I was hit with this error:

```
ExecuteError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
In  [22]:
Line 1:     arcpy.management.AddField(r"C:\Users\acarbo\Documents\ArcGIS\Projects\PythonTest.GDB\Admin2", "Country_Name", "TEXT", field_length=10, field_alias="Name")

File C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\management.py, in AddField:
Line 5345:  raise e

File C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\management.py, in AddField:
Line 5342:  retval = convertArcObjectToPythonObject(gp.AddField_management(*gp_fixargs((in_table, field_name, field_type, field_precision, field_scale, field_length, field_alias, field_is_nullable, field_is_required, field_domain), True)))

File C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py, in <lambda>:
Line 512:   return lambda *args: val(*gp_fixargs(args, True))

ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Try specifying all paramater names: `arcpy.management.AddField(in_table=r"C:\Users\acarbo\Documents\ArcGIS\Projects\PythonTest.GDB\Admin2", field_name="Country_Name", field_type="TEXT", field_length=10, field_alias="Name")`

Comment: There should be an error code after the ExecuteError that shines a bit more light on the speciific issue.  What ArcGIS ERROR code got returned?